# How can I create multi-level projects and multiple installers in one CMake project?

Tags: cmake

I have the following project form (in **Visual Studio** terminology):

- MainProject solution

  - MainProjectA Project
  - MainProjectB Project
- Plugin1 solution

  - Plugin1A Project
  - Plugin1B Project
- Plugin2 solution (and the projects...)

Now, if I try to "convert" this terminology to CMake it would be (I think):

- MainProject project (using "project()")

  - MainProjectA target (set by add_library(), add_executable() or add_custom_target())
  - MainProjectB target
- Plugin1 project

  - Plugin1A target
  - Plugin1B target
- Plugin2 project... (and the targets...)

It is important to point out, each "project/solution" has its own installer (i.e. DEB, MSI, PKG) created by CPack.

---

Is it possible to create the above multi-level CMake project (i.e. Having another level "above" "CMake project"/"VS solution")?

If it is possible, what is the correct/standard way to define/structure it? Do notice, each "project/solution" has its own installer (created with CPack).

I prefer this kind of structure as the different projects/solutions share configurations, and I don't want to replicate the configurations across the different projects.

I would prefer to avoid "ExternalProject_Add", but having a multi-level "tree" - if it is possible.

Comment: Question with some relevance: [How to specify CMake Preset for subdirectories?](/q/75165228/11107541)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem you're trying to solve is that the two buildsystems tend to share buildsystem configuration variables, you can solve the problem by creating [a presets file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html) and sharing it between them. [The `include` field](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html#includes) can help with this sharing.

I don't know how this would work with CPack since I've never done this myself, but you can also create a CMakeLists.txt in the common parent directory and in that CMakeLists.txt, declare a `project()` and `add_subdirectory()` the two sub-projects.